# Image resize and get data in a buffer using python

Tags: python, image, resize

I want to resize the input image to a fixed size. Then I want to entire content of the resized image file in a buffer for further use like, appending it with other buffer(data).

Currently I am doing it using the following python function,

```
def get_resize_img(img_file):
    img = Image.open(img_file)
    img = img.resize((640,960), Image.NEAREST)
    img.save("tmp_out.jpg")
    fp = open("tmp_out.jpg", "rb")
    data = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    print "img sz:", len(data)
    return data
```

Is there any better way to achieve this without writing into a dummy file (tmp_out.jpg) and reading back from it.

-Mohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import StringIO

def get_resize_img(img_file):
    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    img = Image.open(img_file)
    img = img.resize((640,960), Image.NEAREST)
    format = "YOUR_FORMAT" // JPG,PNG,etc.
    img.save(buffer,format)
    return buffer.getvalue()
```

Comment: I get key error when using `format="JPG"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `getdata` to get the image data, which is in fact the image buffer. Then you can reconstruct the image using `frombuffer`. Or maybe you can just return the resized Image object and use it later.

You can check out the [document](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) here.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using numpy then following can be done

```
data = numpy.asarray(im)
```